# Dynamically get the value from DIV class / Label class

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I have this:

```
<div class="keyinfo">
<label for="ctl00_ContentHolder_DecisionControl_ctl00_lb_ApplicationReference">Application Number:</label>

<label class="formanswer">C017206461P</label> 
</div>
<br />
```

The number C017206461P will change each time. I need to capture it and store it in a variable.

My C# code in Selenium webdriver:

```
string val1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[@class='formanswer']")).Text;
```

And also tried

```
string val1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[*[@class='Keyinfo']]//label[*[@class='formanswer']]")).Text;
```

But it does not work; it gives the value for Val1 as Null.

Can you please suggest how to get the dynamically changing values?

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath:

```
"//div[contains(@class, 'keyinfo')]/label[contains(@class, 'formanswer')]"
```

So to grab the text, you would do this:

```
string elementXPath = "//div[contains(@class, 'keyinfo')]/label[contains(@class, 'formanswer')]"
string wantedText = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(elementXPath)).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var scriptExecutor = driver as JavaScriptExecutor;
var result = scriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("return $('.formanswer').first().val();").ToString();
```